# $x^{2}+y^{2}=6xy$ find the value of: $\frac{x+y}{x-y}$

Tags: contest-math

$x$ and $y$ are both positive real numbers :

My attempt:

$$x^{2}+y^{2}=6xy \Leftrightarrow x^{2}+y^{2}-2xy=4xy \Leftrightarrow (x-y)^{2}=4xy \Leftrightarrow (x-y)=\frac{4xy}{x-y} $$
A little note here: $x$ doesn’t equal to $y$.

And now let’s plug this result to $\frac{x+y}{x-y} $:
$$\frac{x+y}{x-y} = (x+y) \cdot \frac{x-y}{4xy}=\frac{x^{2}-y^{2}}{4xy}=\frac{x}{4y}-\frac{y}{4x}$$
And the problem here is to figure out the value of:
$$\frac{x}{y}-\frac{y}{x} $$
Thank you for your help

Comment: You could mention (somewhere in your proof) that $x=y$ in $x^2+y^2=6xy$ iff $x=y=0$, in which case $\frac{x+y}{x-y}$ is an indeterminate form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed as you did:
\begin{equation}
x^2+y^2=6xy\Longrightarrow\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x^2+y^2+2xy=8xy\Longrightarrow(x+y)^2=8xy,\\
x^2+y^2-2xy=4xy\Longrightarrow(x-y)^2=4xy.
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
Then divide both right-side equations and you have it.
$$\left(\frac{x+y}{x-y}\right)^2=\frac{8xy}{4xy}=2\Longrightarrow\frac{x+y}{x-y}=\pm\sqrt{2}.$$
Then,
$$x>y\Longrightarrow\frac{x+y}{x-y}=\sqrt{2},\quad x<y\Longrightarrow\frac{x+y}{x-y}=-\sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: Not quite. You're still missing the final step of verifying that these are indeed solutions (IE See my solution). Always be careful when manipulating non-linear system of equations, as you may have introduced extraneous solutions.

Comment: @Juan Castano you are wrong $(x-y)^{2}=4xy$

Comment: @ Juan Castano Can you add the solutions to your answer

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2=4xy$$

Use this in your equation
$$(x-y)^2=4xy$$
$$(x-y)^2=(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2$$
$$\Rightarrow \dfrac{(x+y)^2}{(x-y)^2}=2$$
$$\Rightarrow \dfrac{x+y}{x-y}=\pm \sqrt{2}$$

Here both positive and negative values are possible depending on whether $x$ is larger or smaller than $y$.

Comment: Note: You should make an argument for why that expression can take on both values. IE So far, you've only shown that it could take on either of those values, but not that it must take on either of those values.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes. I did, thankyou :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Treat the original equation as a quadratic in $x/y$, so you can find that value (2 possible values, corresponding to $\pm$).
Then, express the desired expression in term of $x/y$, and hence find the expression. (Again, there are 2 possible values).

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

What is the numerator and denominator of $ \left( \frac{x+y}{x-y} \right) ^ 2$ in terms of $xy$?

Now, because $x,y$ can be swapped, explain why the expression can take on both positive and negative values.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**
$$x^2+y^2+2xy=6xy+2xy$$

$$\implies (x+y)^2=8xy$$
$$\implies (x+y)=\pm 2\sqrt{2xy}$$
and
$$x^2+y^2-2xy=6xy-2xy$$
$$\implies (x-y)^2=4xy$$